# C to Fpga error with LCD under Altera DE2-70 board

Tags: intel-fpga, hardware-interface, systemc

I tried to display ASCII on the LCD, I am using a DE2-70 board and Handel-C using the Altera DE2 function library. This is the code I am compiling:

```
set clock = external "N2"; 
#include "DE2.hch"

void main(void) {

DE2_LCD_LINE line;

line = hex2ascii(0x1<-4) @ sp @ H @ e @ l @ l @ o @ sp @ w @ o @ r @ l @ d @ blank_line<-152;

DE2LCDDriver(line);
 }
```

I followed all the steps on the documentation and always get this error:

```
undefined width for all used variables sp@ H@e .....etc
```

Comment: Why the VHDL and Verilog tags?

Comment: @David Koontz because I am using DE2-70 that can also programmed using vhdl or verilog. Hopefully someone would help

Comment: unspecified width appears to mean a missing width attribute. Looking in de2.hch it says `extern macro expr sp;`, etc. Looking in de2.hcc shows `extern macro expr sp = 0x20<-8;` etc. with the width. DE2 Library Manual, Using the support library, Installing the Library, Setting up DK - 4. Add the DE2 library (Select Project>Settings, under the Linker tab add de2.hcl to the Object/library modules, path: de2lib\de2.hcl)

Comment: @David Koontz I followed all these steps, and still getting the same error. It is very annoying error.  Do you have any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, this library is no more supported in the new DK5 the best way to use it is to convert to hex then display it as following:

```
/* Convert to HEX*/
y =5;
Unsigned 8 decode_to_hex(unsigned 4 x) 
{
}

/*Then display using */

Line = (decode_to_hex(y)<-8) @0;
DE2LCDDriver(Line);
```